# browser not launched while running from terminal using cypress

Tags: cypress

I am running the below command from terminal.

```
npx cypress run --browser chrome --spec "cypress/integration/SmokeTests/CreateDepartment.ts"
```

The application is not launched in chrome browser instead runs in headless mode. I haven't included --headless in the above command. Any idea why this command runs the tests in headless mode?

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Cypress will run tests headlessly during `cypress run`.

[Source](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-headed)